# mysql insert null data into NOT NULL column

Tags: mysql, null, sql-insert, sql-mode

I'm confused when inserting null data (records with null field) into NOT NULL columns.
The mysql table disables STRICT-SQL-MODE.
According to thess two docs, it was supposed to work but the truth is not.

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-strict
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-type-defaults.html#data-type-defaults-implicit

> For data entry into a NOT NULL column that has no explicit DEFAULT clause, if an INSERT or REPLACE statement includes no value for the column, or an UPDATE statement sets the column to NULL, MySQL handles the column according to the SQL mode in effect at the time:
>
> - If strict SQL mode is enabled, an error occurs for transactional tables and the statement is rolled back. For nontransactional tables, an error occurs, but if this happens for the second or subsequent row of a multiple-row statement, the preceding rows are inserted.
> - If strict mode is not enabled, MySQL sets the column to the implicit default value for the column data type.

When I insert a batch of records (with null field), for example 100 records, it works.

But when I  insert only one record with null field, it failes with the message: `ERROR 1048 (23000): Column 'int_without_default' cannot be null`.

**My question is how to insert single record with null field into NOT NULL column.**

---

Here is the test case I made:

1. Create a table with two columns with 'NOT NULL' requirement:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `test_table` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'ID',
  `int_without_default` int(11) NOT NULL, 
  `int_with_default` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COMMENT='for test';
```

Sql mode of the table

```bash
mysql> SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode;
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| @@GLOBAL.sql_mode                                                                                                                         |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select @@SESSION.sql_mode;
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| @@SESSION.sql_mode                                                                                                                        |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

2. Inserting single record with null caused failure:

```sql
-- ERROR 1048 (23000): Column 'int_without_default' cannot be null
insert into `test_table` (`int_without_default`,`int_with_default`)
value (null, 123);

-- ERROR 1048 (23000): Column 'int_with_default' cannot be null
insert into `test_table` (`int_without_default`,`int_with_default`) 
value (123, null);

-- ERROR 1048 (23000): Column 'int_without_default' cannot be null
insert into `test_table` (`int_without_default`,`int_with_default`) 
values (null, 123);

-- ERROR 1048 (23000): Column 'int_with_default' cannot be null
insert into `test_table` (`int_without_default`,`int_with_default`) 
values (123, null);
```

3. But inserting multiple records with null worked. (I print the result below)

```sql
-- success
insert into `test_table` (`int_without_default`,`int_with_default`) 
values 
(null, 123),
(null, 456);

-- success
insert into `test_table` (`int_without_default`,`int_with_default`) 
values
(123, null),
(456, null);

-- ERROR 1048 (23000): Column 'int_without_default' cannot be null
insert into `test_table` (`int_without_default`,`int_with_default`) 
values
(null, null);

-- success
insert into `test_table` (`int_without_default`,`int_with_default`) 
values
(null, null),
(null, null);
```

4. After executing above sql statement, the content of the table:

```bash
mysql> select * from test_table;
+----+---------------------+------------------+
| id | int_without_default | int_with_default |
+----+---------------------+------------------+
|  1 |                   0 |              123 |
|  2 |                   0 |              456 |
|  3 |                 123 |                0 |
|  4 |                 456 |                0 |
|  5 |                   0 |                0 |
|  6 |                   0 |                0 |
+----+---------------------+------------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

[operation screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxwz7.png)

Comment: *how to insert single record with null field into NOT NULL column.* noway. The only option is to remove NOT NULL from the column definition.

Comment: Strict mode is enable based on your sql mode value list. I'm a bit surprised that bulk insert works.

Comment: Hi @Akina  Sorry for that I forgot that I had set the session sql mode to NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION.

But the bulk insert did work and single insert didn't.
I add an image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxwz7.png.

Comment: The mysql version is :
Server version: 5.7.40 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Comment: Hi @Shadow, I forgot that I had set session sql mode to NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION.

Bulk insert works but single insert doesn't, is this normal? Or there are some other options  to make single insert works too?

I tried to let session sql mode = '', but still the same.

Comment: This was reported as [a bug in 2018](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=90848), but so far there has been no explanation or workaround. I suggest you log into the bug system and click the "Affects Me" button, that's a way to help raise the priority of the bug.